# Why state_id field is not create in regions table definition?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I try to refactor my old database from laravel 5.x to laravel 8 and having 2 related tables:
database/migrations/2019_05_21_144910_create_states_table.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateStatesTable extends Migration {

   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
      Schema::create('states', function(Blueprint $table)
      {
            $table->smallIncrements('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('code', 3)->unique();
         $table->string('name', 50)->unique();
         $table->string('slug', 55)->unique();
            $table->enum('active', ['A', 'I'])->default('I')->comment(' A=>Active, I=>Inactive');
         $table->index(['active','code'], 'fk_states_active_code_ixd');
         $table->index(['active','slug'], 'fk_states_active_slug_ixd');
      });
   }


   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
      Schema::drop('states');
   }

}
```

and database/migrations/2019_05_21_145001_create_regions_table.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateRegionsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->smallIncrements('id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');


            $table->string('name', 50);
            $table->string('slug', 55)->unique();

            $table->enum('active', ['A', 'I'])->default('I')->comment(' A=>Active, I=>Inactive');

            $table->unique(['state_id', 'name']);

            $table->index(['state_id', 'active'], 'fk_regions_state_id_active_ixd');
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('regions');
    }

}
```

I got error running migration command :

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
...
Migrating: 2019_05_21_144910_create_states_table
Migrated:  2019_05_21_144910_create_states_table (626.91ms)
Migrating: 2019_05_21_145001_create_regions_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'state_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `regions` add constraint `regions_state_id_foreign` foreign key (`state_id`) references `states` (`id`) on delete RESTRICT on update RESTRICT)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703
    699▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    700▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    701▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    702▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 703▕             throw new QueryException(
    704▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    705▕             );
    706▕         }
    707▕     }

      +9 vendor frames 
  10  database/migrations/2019_05_21_145001_create_regions_table.php:31
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

      +32 vendor frames 
  43  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

and in regions table I have regions table, but without state_id field. Looks like line

```
$table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

was ignored and I can not catch why? Tried several times...

**Updated 2 :**
I modifie CreateRegionsTable as :

```
Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->smallIncrements('id')->unsigned();
   $table->foreignId('state_id')->constrained('states')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

But I got other error :

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'state_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'regions_state_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `regions` add constraint `regions_state_id_foreign` foreign key (`state_id`) references `states` (`id`) on delete RESTRICT on update RESTRICT)
```

In database/migrations/2019_05_21_144910_create_states_table.php I have :

```
Schema::create('states', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->smallIncrements('id')->unsigned();
```

I suppose that foreignId is incompatible with smallIncrements... But which is valid way ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `foreign` adds the constraint on an existing column. Use `foreignId('state_id')->constrained()` to both create the column and the foreign key index. More in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table->foreign()` method only adds foreign key constraint to an existing column. The method you are looking for is `$table->foreignId()`

so instead of

```
$table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('states')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

in your regions table migration, you should do

```
$table->foreignId('state_id')->constrained('states')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

[documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: Pls, take a look in Updated 2

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  `$table->foreignId('state_id')` method by default adds a bigInteger data type column, while `$table->smallIncrements()` adds a smallInteger data type column. you cannot add foreign key constraints to two different data type columns. You can either change your id column of states table to `bigIncrements()` or in your regions table, first create a smallInteger() column for state_id, and then add foreign key constraints to it.

Comment: Please note that smallInteger columns have a max limit of 32,767. so its safer to use bigIntegers instead